Проблема с матрицей вида в OpenTK
Я написал программу, используя OpenTK(с#), которая выводит картинку на экран. Следующий этап - добавить камеру, передвигающуюся при нажатии AWSD. Если что, в основе моего кода лежит довольно популярный учебник https://opentk.net/learn/chapter1 .
Для этого я создал класс Camera для имитации камеры:
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;
using OpenTK.Mathematics;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Common;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop;
using OpenTK.Windowing.GraphicsLibraryFramework;

namespace engine_0._0._1
{
internal class Camera
{
    public float speed;
    Vector3 position;
    Vector3 target;
    Vector3 up;
    Matrix4 view;

    public Camera(float normalSpeed, Shader shader)
    {
        position = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);
        target = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        up = Vector3.UnitY;
        speed = normalSpeed;
        view = Matrix4.LookAt(position, target, up);

        shader.SetMatrix4("view", view);
    }

    public void ChangeSpeed(float newSpeed)
    {
        speed = newSpeed;
    }
    public void Go(KeyboardState input, FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        if (input.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            position += target * speed * (float)e.Time;
        }
        if (input.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        {
            position -= target * speed * (float)e.Time;
        }
        if (input.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            position += Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(target, up)) * speed * (float)e.Time;
        }
        if (input.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            position -= Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(target, up)) * speed * (float)e.Time;
        }
    }
}
}

Далее в главном классе Window создаю экземпляр класса Camera:
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;
using OpenTK.Mathematics;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Common;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop;
using OpenTK.Windowing.GraphicsLibraryFramework;

namespace engine_0._0._1
{
internal class Window : GameWindow
{
    float[] vertices;
    uint[] indices;
    Shader shader;
    Camera cam;
    int vertexBufferObject;
    int vertexArrayObject;
    int elementBufferObject;
    Matrix4 view;
    public Window(int width, int height, string title) : base(GameWindowSettings.Default, new NativeWindowSettings() { Size = (width, height), Title = title }) { }

    protected override void OnLoad()
    {
        base.OnLoad();

        GL.ClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        //Не обращайте внимания, этот код точно рабочий
        Map map = new Map(@"Maps\m1.txt");
        vertices = map.vertices;
        indices = map.indices;

        shader = new Shader(@"Shaders\shader.vert", @"Shaders\shader.frag");

        cam = new Camera(1.5f, shader); // ИНИЦИЛИЗИРУЮ КАМЕРУ СРАЗУ ПОСЛЕ ИНИЦИАЛИЗАЦИИ ШЕЙДЕРА
        //этот код точно рабочий
        // Создаю VBO
        vertexBufferObject = GL.GenBuffer();
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertexBufferObject);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertices.Length * sizeof(float), vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        //этот код точно рабочий
        // Создаю VAO
        vertexArrayObject = GL.GenVertexArray();
        GL.BindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 6 * sizeof(float), 0);
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        //этот код точно рабочий
        int texCoordLocation = shader.GetAttribLocation("aTexCoord");
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(texCoordLocation, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 6 * sizeof(float), 3 * sizeof(float));
        
        Texture ground = new Texture(@"Tiles\grass.png", TextureUnit.Texture0);
        Texture lava = new Texture(@"Tiles\lava.png", TextureUnit.Texture1);
        
        shader.SetInt("ground", 0);
        shader.SetInt("lava", 1);
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordLocation);
        
        //этот код точно рабочий
        //tiles VAP
        int tileTypeLocation = shader.GetAttribLocation("aTileType");
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(tileTypeLocation, 1, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 6 * sizeof(float), 5 * sizeof(float));
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(tileTypeLocation);

        elementBufferObject = GL.GenBuffer();
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, elementBufferObject);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, indices.Length * sizeof(uint), indices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

        shader.Use();

        //Code goes here
    }

    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRenderFrame(e);

        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);

        //Code goes here.

        shader.Use();
        GL.BindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);

        GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);

        SwapBuffers();
    }
    protected override void OnUpdateFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnUpdateFrame(e);

        if (KeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
        {
            Close();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnResize(ResizeEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);

        GL.Viewport(0, 0, e.Width, e.Height);
    }

    protected override void OnUnload()
    {
        // Unbind all the resources by binding the targets to 0/null.
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
        GL.BindVertexArray(0);
        GL.UseProgram(0);

        // Delete all the resources.
        GL.DeleteBuffer(vertexBufferObject);
        GL.DeleteVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);

        GL.DeleteProgram(shader.Handle);

        base.OnUnload();
    }
}
}

А так же код вершинного шейдера:
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPosition;

layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

layout (location = 2) in float aTileType;

uniform mat4 view;

out vec2 TexCoord;
out float TileType;

void main()
{
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
    TileType = aTileType;
    gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 1.0f) * view;
}

Сама проблема в том, что пока я не добавил в код камеру, программа вела себя правильно, но после добавления камеры картинка полностью пропала(но код скомпилировался)
Вот и не знаю, что делать?

Отлаживайте. Возвращайте как было и добавляйте проблемный код по частям, пока "не сломается". Потом изучаете почему ломается на минимальном примере.

@Kromster, попробую. Проблема в том, что картинка пропадает в тот момент, когда матрица вида подключена к шейдеру. Сама матрица настраивается в конструкторе класса Camera. Отсюда вывод, что какой-то из переменных(up/front/position) присвоено неподходящее значение, но при этом значения я брал ИЗ УЧЕБНИКА, предполагая, что там значения правильные

К тому же появилась новая проблема. Было бы неплохо знать значение gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 1.0f) * view(тогда бы я смог хотя бы понять координаты вершин), но отладчик не показывает процессы в шейдерах, видимо потому что они написаны на GLSL, а не на c#. Но все же есть некоторые продвижения благодаря вам я нашел силы тщательнее разобраться с методом lookAt и немного изменил код класса Camera

Можете попробовать передавать единичную матрицу вида, чтобы проверить что она передается корректно.

Спасибо вам. Проблема была в шейдере. Всего то нужно было поменять gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 1.0f) * view; на gl_Position = view * vec4(aPosition, 1.0f); хотя я не видел такого порядка ни в одном источнике. @Kromster, если вы не против, я бы попросил посмотреть другой мой вопрос на эту тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1580804/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-opentk

Справедливости ради, у меня везде в GLSL такой порядок - gl_Position = mProj * mView * mModel * vec4(vaPosition, 1.0);

По второму вопросу не подскажу, по видео непонятно что у вас там. Я обычнов каком-нибудь Блендере значения проверяю, если есть сомнения.

gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 1.0f) * view; на gl_Position = view * vec4(aPosition, 1.0f); это транспонированные действия. Значит у вас матрица не в том порядке как традиционно,  а транспонирована ( базис - вектор строка а не столбец). Да. в книгах по математике    базис по столбцам, но для вычислений на компьютере это "неудобно". Возможно библиотека это игнорирует

Для начала стоит попробовать передавать единичную матрицу вида, чтобы проверить что она передается корректно.
Скорее всего у вас неправильный порядок умножения. У меня в GLSL всегда "задом-наперед", т.е. vertex * MVP записан как PVM * vertex:
gl_Position = mProj * mView * mModel * vec4(vaPosition, 1.0);


PVM * vertex это как раз прямой порядок если вы считаете векторы столбцами, vertex * MVP обратный, если вектор-строка.
