Неправильное поведение камеры в opentk
Написал программу, которая выводит картинку на экран(выводит игровую карту). Следующий этап -- сделать симуляцию камеры, которая двигается при нажатии AWSD.
Код класса камеры
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;
using OpenTK.Mathematics;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Common;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop;
using OpenTK.Windowing.GraphicsLibraryFramework;

namespace engine_0._0._1
{
internal class Camera
{
    public float speed;
    Vector3 position;
    Vector3 target;
    Vector3 up;
    Vector3 right;
    Matrix4 view;

    public Camera(float normalSpeed, Shader shader)
    {
        position = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f); //позиция камеры
        target = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //точка в которую камера всегда должна смотреть
        up = new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);// вектор вверх
        right = new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);//вектор вправо
        speed = normalSpeed;// скорость передвижения камеры
        Use(shader);
    }

    public void ChangeSpeed(float newSpeed)
    {
        speed = newSpeed;// метод для изменения скорости передвижения камеры
    }
    public void Go(KeyboardState input, FrameEventArgs e, Shader shader)
    {//Метод для передвижения камеры(вызывается при каждом обновлении кадра)

        if (input.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            position += up * speed * (float)e.Time;
            Use(shader);
        }
        if (input.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        {
            position -= up * speed * (float)e.Time;
            Use(shader);
        }
        if (input.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            position += right * speed * (float)e.Time;
            Use(shader);
        }
        if (input.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            position -= right * speed * (float)e.Time;
            Use(shader);
        }
    }
    public void Use(Shader shader)
    {//метод для создания и передачи матрица в шейдер
        view = Matrix4.LookAt(position, target, up);
        shader.SetMatrix4("view", view);
    }
}
}

результатом должно быть перемещение карты в 2д плоскости(как в 2д игре), но результат получается как на видео https://youtu.be/e6Smpl9RiBo
На сколько я понимаю, камера передвигается верно, но не привязывает свое направление к заданной точке target(0;0;0), но как я ни пытался менять параметры метода LookAt, результат не получился такой как нужно
Возможно будет полезно, вот учебник opentk, который я использовал https://opentk.net/learn/chapter1/9-camera.html?tabs=input-opentk4%2Cdelta-time-input-opentk4%2Ccursor-mode-opentk4%2Cmouse-move-opentk4%2Cscroll-opentk4
И еще моя догадка, возможно такая проблема из-за того, что я не сделал матрицу проекции или модели?

Если нужно, чтобы камера летала над картой и смотрела рвно в точку под себя, то точка  куда смотрит камета должна перемещаться вместе с ней. То есть к примеру, положение камеры 1,1,3, тогда точка, куда смотрит камера 1,1,0. Если камера 3,5,3, то точка 3,5,0. И так далее. То есть меняются координаты положения самой камеры, а её вектор поворота (up) и вектор направления (forward) - не меняются вообще. То есть код должен стать ещё проще.

Окей, я правильно понял, что при нажатии клавиш значение target должно меняться вместе с position?

LookAt меняет вектор forward камеры. В вашем случае его менять вообще не нужно. Меняйте только положение камеры в пространстве, больше ничего.

@aepot, кажется я не понимаю о чем вы. На сколько я вижу, при нажатии клавиш как раз и меняется поле position, т.е. положение камеры. Напишите пожалуйста конкретно, что мне нужно изменить  в коде. Нужно заменить lookAt на  view = Matrix4.LookAt(position, target, up)?

Я не шарю в OpenTK, поэтому кода не напишу, но я работал с камерой в Unity. Смысл в том, что есть 3 вещи: положение камеры, поворот камеры и направлене камеры. Чтобы передвигать камеру над плоскостью, и чтобы она всегда смотрела только под себя, вам нужно менять только положение. Остальные 2 параметра задать только изначально и не менять в будущем. Разберитесь, как этими тремя штуками управлять отдельно и всё станет понятно.

Спасибо, но, видимо, в opentk это работает немного по-другому)
я не меняю ничего кроме position

Как именно пишется код - не важно, важно понимать, как это на уровне логики контролировать. Я про логические штуки говорю, а не про какие-то там отдельные свойства камеры в OpenTK.

Я понял. Если я правильно понял, вы предполагаете, что кроме позиции камеры изменяется еще какой-то параметр камеры. Я не вижу в коде чтобы изменялось что-то кроме позиции

Окей, самый первый комментарий. Попробуйте target перемещать по x,y одновременно с position

Да, это я сразу же попробовал. Я задал вектор target так: target(position.X, position.Y, 0.0f), таким образом координаты цели такие же как у камеры, но с нулевым Z. К сожалению это не привело к нужному результату :(

Тогда я сдаюсь.

спасибо за помощь, надеюсь, кто-то другой поможет)

Оказалось, что проблема решается добавлением перспективной матрицы проекции. Теперь все работает. Если я правильно понял, то пока не добавлена матрица проекции, не определяется пространство отсечения, следовательно вместо того, чтобы просто не рисовать координаты за пространством отсечения, opentk сжимает изображение, чтобы уместить в окне все вершины, это и дает эффект как на видео. Но это не работает с ортогональной проекцией, и я пока не понял почему

Покажите код, как именно вы решили проблему, вдруг это кому-то пригодится.
